# convert multi D array into vector Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, indexing

Thanks in advance for the help

Suppose I have a multi D array such that

```
x(:,:,1) = [1 2 ; 3 4];
x(:,:,2) = [5 6 ; 7 8];
x(:,:,3) = [9 10 ; 11 12];
```

I would like quickly and efficiently convert x into

```
y = [1 5 9 2 6 10 3 7 11 4 8 12];
```

I there an efficient way to go about this besides using loops (the matrix I would like to do this to is relatively large)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the colon operator `:` but you first have to reorder the matrix `x`:

```
x(:,:,1) = [1 2 ; 3 4];
x(:,:,2) = [5 6 ; 7 8];
x(:,:,3) = [9 10 ; 11 12];
z=permute(x,[3 2 1]);
y=z(:).'
```